# Nginx Redirect to request_uri

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I want to achieve with Nginx return or rewrite option to redirect user request based on request_uri.

For example, if user request page mysite.com/test.com then he should be redirected to test.com.It should auto-redirect user to request_uri by removing domain mysite.com/ from request_url.

I tried many options available online but it gives too many redirect error.

Comment: Can you post your config?

Comment: return 301  $request_uri;
I want to do this for whole domain,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following config should do the trick:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    location = / {
        @do-here-what-you-want-for-homepage
    }
    location / {
        return 301 http:/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that do the work. How to add exception only for the homepage? Btw it is the answer to my original question so I will vote it for the answer.

Comment: @user3259496 check the update.